# Mutate a column counting only 1 - 2 - 3 - 1 - 2 - 3

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a dataframe that is 10,000+ rows large, and I want to mutate a column that labels each row either 1, 2 or 3. Starting from the first row = 1, the second = 2, the third = 3, and then starting again from 1 for the fourth row, repeating through the entire dataframe.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately I get the following error: Error: Assigned data `1:3` must be compatible with existing data. x Existing data has 12 rows. x Assigned data has 3 rows. ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeat vector to fill down column in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462626/repeat-vector-to-fill-down-column-in-data-frame)

Comment: It does but the way the question is phrased bears only slight resemblance to the problem at hand so I was not able to find it. I would suggest amending the question before declaring it the definitive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If number of rows is exactly divisible by the length of the vector then you can use :

```
df$row <- 1:3
```

A general solution would be to repeat `1:3` till number of rows in the dataframe.

```
df$row <- rep(1:3, length.out = nrow(df))
```